# How to fix in-place operation in recurrent cycle Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

So, when I'm calling

```
for data, label in train_loader:  
      a, cutoff = model(torch.t(data),R,1)
      loss = (cutoff-label)**2
      loss.backward()
```

I have this

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation 
has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 1]], 
which is output 0 of SelectBackward, is at version 51; 
expected version 50 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows 
the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable 
in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

There is my Net forward function

```
 def forward(self, x,R,L):
          a = torch.zeros(R,L,1)
          for cycle in range (R):
           if cycle ==0:  
               a[0]=(self.w*torch.mm(self.wih,x))

           a[cycle]= relu(torch.mm(self.whh,a[cycle-1])+ (self.w*torch.mm(self.wih,x)))            
          cutoff =(sqr(torch.norm(torch.mm(torch.t(self.wih),a[R-1])))/sqr(torch.norm(x)))
          return a, cutoff
```

And problem is in

```
a[cycle] = .....a[cycle-1]....
```

And that `cutoff` is using `a[R-1]`
How can I fix this in-place operation or cycle?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\A877\untitled2.py", line 69, in <module>
    loss.backward()

  File "C:\Users\A877\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 195, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)

  File "C:\Users\A877\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 97, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
```

Comment: "_Hint: the backtrace further above shows 
the operation that failed to compute its gradient._" Could you share the backtrace as well?

Comment: Yeah, I have added in description

Comment: I think problem in ```cycle``` variable changing.